# can a many2many field in openerp/odoo be searchable?

Tags: odoo

I've added a many2many field in res.partner:

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _columns = {
        'available_in': fields.many2many('res.country.state', 'copertura_country_state_rel', 'partner_id', 'country_state_id',),
    }
```

And I now want to be able to search in partners list for "partners available in this country.state", but it seems the field can't be made searchable in a simple way (or I am missing something ?)